# lattices in the complex plane from 3 elements

Tags: complex-numbers, integer-lattices, free-modules

I am asked to find when, for some nonzero complex numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, the set defined by $\{l\alpha+m\beta+n\gamma|l,m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a lattice. Assuming it is a lattice, I constructed a homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, and I think I successfully deduced that thus would imply that $a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma=0$ where not all of $a,b,c$ are zero (and at most one pair is dependent).

I believe the converse is true: if $a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma=0$ then they generate a lattice. I proved that if two are dependent this is true. However, I am having a very hard time proving that if all three are dependent this is true.

My intuition is that if $a\alpha+b\beta=-c\gamma$, then the set $\{l\alpha+m\beta+n\gamma|l,m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is simply the lattice generated by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ contracted by a factor of $1/c$ in the direction parallel to $\gamma$. I'm not completely sure how to put this into math, let alone prove it. I feel like my method is leading to some kind of trigonometry, but I feel like there must be a better way to prove this. Is the statement even true?

Comment: Perhaps the Wikipedia article [Fundamental pair of periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_pair_of_periods) can help you.

Comment: I'm still having a lot of trouble. I've reduced the problem to finding basis elements for the lattice generated by the plane points added to multiples of a vector $(a/c,b/c)$. I am trying to find an expression for basis elements, but I'm having a LOT of trouble