Is the set Z+aZ+bZ dense in the complex plane?
Let $a$ and $b$ be complex numbers. Under which conditions on $a$ and $b$ is the set $\mathbb{Z}+a\mathbb{Z}+b\mathbb{Z}$ dense in $\mathbb{C}$?
I have interest in the following case: $\Im a\neq0,$ $\Im b\neq0,$ and the numbers $\Re a,$ $\Re b$ and $\Im a/\Im b$ are irrationals.

FWIW, this question is kind of a converse to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182825/lattices-in-the-complex-plane-from-3-elements. That question asked when the set was a lattice. You're more interested in the other direction: when the set is as far from a lattice as possible. I think it's a good question.

Probably that you need $0 \neq \arg a \neq \arg b \neq 0\mod 2 \pi$

And some condition about irrationality of their modules or imaginary parts
